# Else statement is not applying

Tags: php, if-statement

Why does the last else statement in my PHP code is not working? When I entered non-existing accounts, it is not displaying the "Incorrect email or password" error message.

```
<?php

include("connection.php");

$email_id = $password = $emailErr = $passErr = $loginErr = "";

if(isset($_POST["butLogin"])){
    if(empty($_POST["email_id"])){
        $emailErr = "This field cannot be empty!";
    }else{
        $email_id = $_POST["email_id"];
    }

    if(empty($_POST["password"])){
        $passErr = "This field cannot be empty!";
    }else{
        $password = $_POST["password"];
    }

    if($email_id && $password){
        $check_record = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE password = '$password' AND email = '$email_id'");

        if (mysqli_num_rows($check_record) > 0 ){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check_record);
            if(($email_id == $row['email']) && ($password == $row['password'])){
                if($row['user_type'] == 1){
                    header("Location: /php/admin/index");
                }else{
                    header("Location: /php/user/index");
                }
            }else{
                $loginErr = "Incorrect email or password.";
            }   
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: __Where__ you expect this message to be displayed?

Comment: First off take a look @ [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) & storing real passwords in a table is a really bad idea.

Comment: Because you're never hitting it, because `SELECT * FROM user WHERE password = '$password' AND email = '$email_id'` returns 0 rows.

Comment: And why do you compare values from database __again__?

Comment: `<form method="POST">
 <input type="email" name="email_id">&nbsp;
 <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr ?></span><br><br>
 <input type="password" name="password">&nbsp;
 <span class="error"><?php echo $passErr ?></span><br>
 <span class="error"><?php echo $loginErr ?></span><br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="butLogin" value="Login">&nbsp;
 <a href="">Register</a>
</form>`

in this form @u_mulder

Comment: Thank you!  @AlexK.

Comment: just a note you can use ternary statements to reduce lines: `$passErr = (empty($_POST['password']) ? 'this field cannot be empty' : $_POST['password'] )`

Comment: Note that the line `if(($email_id == $row['email']) && ($password == $row['password']))` is completely useless, because you've already ensured that the email and password match with your query.

Comment: Yeah you're right, my bad for not noticing it. Thank you everyone! I just saw it in a tutorial btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If account doesn't exist, mysqli_num_rows will return 0. You should move the else condition in that block.

```
    if (mysqli_num_rows($check_record) > 0 ){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check_record);
        if(($email_id == $row['email']) && ($password == $row['password'])){
            if($row['user_type'] == 1){
                header("Location: /php/admin/index");
            }else{
                header("Location: /php/user/index");
            }
        }   
    } else{
        $loginErr = "Incorrect email or password.";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! but now it's  displaying "incorrect email or password" that supposed to be displayed **after** I enter something. 


P.S. I get it now, but why does the last else is triggering?

Answer (score 0):

The else statement will never get touched because it is checked on the wrong conditional. If the query returns 0, that is because there is no email/password combination found, but you do not handle this case.

Move your else statement to look like the following:

```
if($email_id && $password){
    $check_record = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE password = '$password' AND email = '$email_id'");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($check_record) > 0 ){

       "QUERY PROCESSING HERE"

    }else{
            $loginErr = "Incorrect email or password.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! but now it's displaying "incorrect email or password" that supposed to be displayed after I enter something. P.S. I get it now, but why does the last else is triggering?